# QRAdar - AQL no viable alternative at input SELECT

Tags: aql, soc, qradar

I'm getting an error when I try to use this query. It works in advanced search tab in log activity. But when I write it into the rule wizard AQL filter query area, it prompts **`AQL no viable alternative at input SELECT`** **warning**. I got this query from Sigma Translater btw.

```
SELECT UTF8(payload) as search_payload from events where (((LOGSOURCETYPENAME(devicetype) ilike 'Microsoft Windows Security Event Log')) and ((("EventID"='1' and search_payload ilike 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe' and search_payload ilike '%\Windows\Caches\NavShExt.dll %')) or (("EventID"='1' and search_payload ilike '%\AppData\Roaming\MICROS~1\Windows\Caches\NavShExt.dll,Setting'))))
```

Comment: When you want to use QRadar AQL statements in a custom rule, you have to use a WHERE clause. It is the part after WHERE statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating rules in QRadar based on AQL you only put the statements that come after the WHERE

In your case:

```html
(((LOGSOURCETYPENAME(devicetype) ilike 'Microsoft Windows Security Event Log')) and ((("EventID"='1' and search_payload ilike 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe' and search_payload ilike '%\Windows\Caches\NavShExt.dll %')) or (("EventID"='1' and search_payload ilike '%\AppData\Roaming\MICROS~1\Windows\Caches\NavShExt.dll,Setting'))))
```

It will then run that statement against the logs and trigger offenses.